# Extracting a pattern from String

Tags: java, string, parsing

I have a Random string from which i need to match a certain pattern and parse it out.

My String-

> {"sid":"zw9cmv1pzybexi","parentId":null,"time":1373271966311,"color":"#e94d57",**"userId":"255863"**,"st":"comment","type":"section","cType":"parent"},{},null,null,null,null,{"sid":"zwldv1lx4f7ovx","parentId":"zw9cmv1pzybexi","time":1373347545798,"color":"#774697",**"userId":"5216907"**,"st":"comment","type":"section","cType":"child"},{},null,null,null,null,null,{"sid":"zw76w68c91mhbs","parentId":"zw9cmv1pzybexi","time":1373356224065,"color":"#774697",**"userId":"5216907"**,"st":"comment","type":"section","cType":"child"},

From the above I want to parse out (using regex) all the values for userId attribute. Can anyone help me out on how to do this ? It is a Random string and not JSON. Can you provide me a regex solution for this ?

Comment: can you show us what you have tried for this?

Comment: Please help yourself by posting the code you have tried

Comment: There is no need to add the major tag in the title.

Answer (score 3):

Is that a random string ? It looks like JSON to me, and if it is I would recommend a [JSON parser](http://json.org/java/) in preference to a regexp. The right thing to do when faced with a particular language/grammar is to use the corresponding parser, rather than a (potentially) fragile regexp.

Comment: It is a Random string and not JSON. Can you provide me a regex solution for this ?

Answer (score 1):

To get the user Ids, you can use this pattern:

```
String input = "{\"sid\":\"zw9cmv1pzybexi\",\"parentId\":null,\"time\":1373271966311,\"color\":\"#e94d57\",\"userId\":\"255863\",\"st\":\"comment\",\"type\":\"section\",\"cType\":\"parent\"},{},null,null,null,null,{\"sid\":\"zwldv1lx4f7ovx\",\"parentId\":\"zw9cmv1pzybexi\",\"time\":1373347545798,\"color\":\"#774697\",\"userId\":\"5216907\",\"st\":\"comment\",\"type\":\"section\",\"cType\":\"child\"},{},null,null,null,null,null,{\"sid\":\"zw76w68c91mhbs\",\"parentId\":\"zw9cmv1pzybexi\",\"time\":1373356224065,\"color\":\"#774697\",\"userId\":\"5216907\",\"st\":\"comment\",\"type\":\"section\",\"cType\":\"child\"},";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"userId\":\"(.*?)\"");
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

which outputs:

```
255863
5216907
5216907
```

If you want the full string `"userId":"xxxx"`, you can use `m.group();` instead of `m.group(1);`.

Comment: Thanks ! This fulfills my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

It's a JSON format, so you have to use a JSON Parser:

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(yourString);
for (int i=0;i<array.length();i++){ 
  JSONObject jo = inputArray.getJSONObject(i);
  userId = jo.getString("userId");
}
```

EDIT : Regex pattern

```
"userId"[ :]+((?=\[)\[[^]]*\]|(?=\{)\{[^\}]*\}|\"[^"]*\")
Result : 
"userId" : "Some user ID (numeric or letters)"
```

Comment: It is a Random string and not JSON. Can you provide me a regex solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Use JSON parser instead of using Regex, your code will be much more readable and maintainable 
http://json.org/java/

https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/

Answer (score 0):

As other already told you, it looks like a JSON String, but if you really want to parse this string on your own, you could use this piece of code:

```
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\"userId\":\"(\\d+)\"");
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

The matcher will match every `"userId":"12345"` pattern. `matcher.group(1)` will return every userId, `12345` in this case (`matcher.group()` without parameter returns the entire group, ie `"userId":"12345"`).

Answer (score 0):

Here's the regex-code you're asking for ..

```
    //assign subject
    String subject = "{\"sid\":\"zw9cmv1pzybexi\",\"parentId\":null,\"time\":1373271966311,\"color\":\"#e94d57\",\"userId\":\"255863\",\"st\":\"comment\",\"type\":\"section\",\"cType\":\"parent\"},{},null,null,null,null,{\"sid\":\"zwldv1lx4f7ovx\",\"parentId\":\"zw9cmv1pzybexi\",\"time\":1373347545798,\"color\":\"#774697\",\"userId\":\"5216907\",\"st\":\"comment\",\"type\":\"section\",\"cType\":\"child\"},{},null,null,null,null,null,{\"sid\":\"zw76w68c91mhbs\",\"parentId\":\"zw9cmv1pzybexi\",\"time\":1373356224065,\"color\":\"#774697\",\"userId\":\"5216907\",\"st\":\"comment\",\"type\":\"section\",\"cType\":\"child\"},";

    //specify pattern and matcher
    Pattern pat = Pattern.compile( "userId\":\"(\\d+)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE|Pattern.DOTALL );
    Matcher mat = pat.matcher( subject );

    //browse all
    while ( mat.find() )
    {
        System.out.println( "result [" + mat.group( 1 ) + "]" );
    }
```

But OF COURSE I´d suggest to solve this using a JSON-Parser like
http://json.org/java/

Greetings
Christopher